# Vercel - Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 127

Tags: javascript, css, vercel, tailwind-css

I wanted to deploy my tailwind project and I got this error and I can’t fix it. Do u have any ideas?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGoZh.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EHSr8.png)

I tried a lot but it seems it doesn’t want to work!

Answer (score 0):

as error clearly says:

```
02:08:29 sh: tailwindcss: command not found
```

most probably you have globally installed `tailwindcss` on your local machine

and therefore Vercel doesn't know such a command

use:

```bash
npx tailwindcss -i ./input.css -0 ./CSS/Style.css
```